# Como puedo leer un arreglo de caracteres en Java?

Tags: java, array

```java
public static void main(String[] args){
    Scanner Leer = new Scanner (System.in);

    char arreglo[] = new char [NUMERO];
    char cadena[] = new char [NUMERO];
    System.out.print("Dame la cadena: ");
    cadena = Leer.nextline();
    mistrcpy(arreglo,cadena);
    System.out.println("Arreglo: " + arreglo);
    System.out.println("Dame la segunda cadena: ");
    cadena = Leer.nextLine();
    mistrcpy(arreglo,cadena);
    System.out.println("Arreglo: " + arreglo);

}
```

Tengo esto pero al momento de leer "cadena" me marca un error, no se como puedo escanear o leer esto.

Answer (score 0):

> > Tengo esto pero al momento de leer "cadena" me marca un error

El problema radica en esta línea:

```java
cadena = Leer.nextline();
```

El método [nextLine()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextLine()) retorna la referencia de un objeto de tipo `String`, sin embargo, la variable `cadena` es de tipo `char[]` (un arreglo de caracteres). El compilador dará un error de compilación, debido a que, los tipos no coinciden.

La forma correcta de hacerlo es cambiar el tipo de la variable `cadena` a `String[]` y recorrer el arreglo de objetos de tipo `String` a través de un bucle y posteriormente, asignar la referencia de un objeto de tipo `String` en cada posición/índice del arreglo.

El código quedaría así:

```java
public static void main(String[] args)
{ 
    Scanner Leer = new Scanner (System.in);

    String arreglo[] = new String[NUMERO];
    String cadena[] = new String[NUMERO];
    for(int i = 0; i < cadena.length; i++)
    {
       System.out.print("Dame la cadena: "+ i);
       cadena[i] = Leer.nextLine();
    }
    mistrcpy(arreglo, cadena);
    System.out.println("Arreglo: " + arreglo);
    for(int i = 0; i < cadena.length; i++)
    {
       System.out.print("Dame la cadena: "+ i);
       cadena[i] = Leer.nextLine();
    }
    mistrcpy(arreglo,cadena);
    System.out.println("Arreglo: " + arreglo);
}
```

Una forma para simplificar el código es creando un método estático en la clase principal (donde está el `main`):

```java
public static void pedirCadena(String[] cadena, String[] arreglo, Scanner leer)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < cadena.length; i++)
    {
        System.out.print("Dame la cadena: "+ i);
        cadena[i] = leer.nextLine();
    }
    mistrcpy(arreglo, cadena);
    System.out.println("Arreglo: " + arreglo);
}
```

Posteriormente, invocas al método de esta manera en el `main`:

```java
public static void main(String[] args)
{ 
    Scanner leer = new Scanner (System.in);
    String arreglo[] = new String[NUMERO];
    String cadena[] = new String[NUMERO];
    pedirCadena(cadena, arreglo, leer);
    pedirCadena(cadena, arreglo, leer);
}
```

**Recomendación:** Los nombres de las variables que apuntan a un objeto, empiezan con minúscula, esto solo es para seguir la convención.

Answer (score -1):

Recuerda que [Scanner.nextLine](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/15/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Scanner.html#nextLine()) te retorna un objeto String, pero puedes convertir ese String a un char array usando el método [String.toCharArray](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/15/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#toCharArray()).

```java
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String... args) {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        char[] myCharArray = scanner.nextLine().toCharArray();

        System.out.println(myCharArray);
        System.out.println(myCharArray.length);
    }

}
```